# Gtk+3 &C & Glade problems

Tags: c, linux, gtk3, glade

I tried to make a simple Gui program with C and Glade on Linux.
I wrote a simple program and design a window with Glade.
When I run the code it says:

```
(gtk-test:23026): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion ‘GTK_IS_WIDGET(widget)’ failed
```

And no Window open.
I searched a bit on the internet but I cant anything helpful. Some say that I have to convert the glade file to .xml but that didn't work.

### C

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "window_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

### Glade

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding="UFT-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes">Test Window</property>
        <property name="default_width">640</property>
        <property name="default_height">480</property>
        <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
        <child>
            <placeholder/>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: `UFT` -=> `UTF`

Comment: As well as what José said, once you've got the file loaded without a `GError`, you should also check whether the return value of `gtk_builder_get_object()` is `NULL`, which indicates a failed lookup and would of course fail the assertion that it's a valid `GtkWidget *`. In this case, it's probably failing because the file simply didn't load successfully, but you should at least verify successful lookup, at least until you've cemented the structure of your `.ui` file and know it'll always succeed. Error-checking exists for a reason - stop just bulldozing past it and expecting things to work.

Comment: I'll update the answer with GError example and with @underscore_d correct indication about checking result og builder get object function/method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you add the xml tag by hand and it's malformed. At the same time you are not doing any error checking from the `gtk_builder_add_from_file` function.

Your xml starts with:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UFT-8>
```

and should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

To avoid this situation you should use GError and check if there are errors when parsing the builder file with `gtk_builder_add_from_file`.

### **EDIT:**

I saw that you have updated the glade file in your question. If you do so then the answer may not be obvious. Anyway, here is your code with error checking for glade file existence and `@underscore_d` tip on checking the `GtkBuilder get_object` function (could use `g_assert` macro instead):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GError          *err = NULL;
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "window_main.glade", &err);

    if (err != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read file: %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        return 1;
    }

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));

    if (window == NULL || !GTK_IS_WINDOW(window)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to get window. (window == NULL || window != GtkWindow)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_window_main_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -rdynamic -o window main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: Yes I add it by hand because I only have it print out at the moment.

Comment: I am new to gtk so I don't know what do you mean with GError. Could you explain this more for me?

Comment: searching would help: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html

Comment: OK when I'm home I'll try

Comment: They also don't check whether the return value of `gtk_builder_get_object()` is `NULL`, which indicates a failed lookup and would of course fail the assertion that it's a valid `GtkWidget *`.

Comment: I take your code and run it, and it says (I have to translate it from german so there might be some errors in the translation) : "Unable to read file File >>window_main.glade<< could not be opened: File not found

Comment: @Harm M-B  Is window_main.glade in the same folder/directory as your executable?

Comment: no I'm working with eclipse and the .glade file is in the same as the source. But when I put the file in the same folder as the excutable, the same error show up

Comment: Is the name an exact match? It must be called window_main.glade

Comment: Yes I copied with ctrl + C from the file name

Comment: The advantage of error checking is this. You now know that the program cant even find the file. Name it window.ui both on then file explorer and on the code. Then try again

Comment: Are you on which os? Windows, linux...?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.03 LTS

Comment: Ok, so create a folder with only your c file, let's call it `main.c` and the glade file, let's keep `window_main.glade`. Then do `gcc -o window main.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\``. Then execute `./window`

Comment: It works!!!! But how can I make it that eclipse compile it? Also it says " (window:8183): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'on_window_main_destroy'. Did you compile with -rdynamic?" If it helps I already installed pkg-config in eclipse

Comment: It complains because the signal handler  `on_window_main_destroy` is not on `main.c`. The -rdynamic it's a gcc flag needed because you defined the signal handler in the glade xml. I'll edit the answer to add the signal handler. Yes, you can add -rdynamic to gcc but the goal was just to validate the concrete problem you are having. Regarding eclipse, that is another question and not sure i can help you. I don't use eclipse and it's specific to the way eclipse invokes a compiler, etc

Comment: @HarmM-B. check the Edit. Added the signal handler and compile command.

Comment: I can' t see what you change in your answer. What editor do you using? Sorry I have not refreshed

Comment: I've added the `on_window_main_destroy` function and the gcc command. Check that the prototype for the callback, to be correct should have 2 arguments. Not needed but should follow the prototype. The editor i use is `vi` but i would suggest Gnome Builder, Anjuta or even gedit (well there's is also Geany, etc). Then use Makefiles (autotools) or meson as build system.

Comment: @JoséFonte Now I'm using Gnome-Builder and I have still the same problems. I'm asking the same Question in the main thread again, but may you can help me.