# Error in c++ compiling of GTK + Glade code in Clion

Tags: c++, gtk, glade

have some problem in compiling this code

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder* builder;
    GtkWidget* window;
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    builder=gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder,"main.glade",NULL);
    window=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window1"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder,NULL);
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

If i compile it with

```
 g++ -o gladewin main.cpp -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic
```

it's ok. but if I do this in CLion I get this error

```
): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Comment: Are you sure the error message you get is from the *building*, and not when running your application?

Comment: It looks like gtk_builder_get_object() is failing (eg. returning NULL). Try checking its return value before instantiating the window.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752987/gtk3-c-glade-problems

Comment: `gtk_builder_add_from_file` has a return type. You should not ignore it. I assume your working directory is not where the glade file is located and opening fails.